# Selenium : How to execute test cases at parallely using cucumber with maven

Tags: maven, selenium, cucumber

We have execute the different test scenarios in different feature file using **cucumber with maven in eclipse**.

**EX:**

**FeatureFile1:Login1**

```
Scenario:UserLogin

Given:the userName is "aaa"

When:the login button is clicked

Then:the user login as successfully
```

**FeatureFile2:Login2**

```
Scenario:UserLogin01

Given:the userName is "bbb"

When:the login button is clicked

Then:the user login as successfully
```

In above example how to **run in parallels** and also how to configure in **pom.xml file**.

Regards,

Gopal

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how to solve it using maven only. I'm using jbehave and run tests in parallel with testng. It provides xml which operates test running and there you could specify amount of parallel threads and what exactly should be paralleled (metods, tests, suits). On build server use maven command:

```
mvn test -Dtestng.xml.file=suite.xml
```

Also you could use surefire plugin with any test provider.
http://testng.org/doc/index.html
http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/index.html